# Can a computer count to infinity?

Tags: counting, mathematical-programming

So, could a computer count to infinity assuming it was a super computer and had near unlimited amounts of ram and hard drive/solid state drive storage? I am being serious when I ask this.
[This is what I am asking]: Wouldn't Infinity mean endless counting, and wouldn't *that* be infinity?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on what you mean by "count to infinity". Specifically, how does the computer give output?

consider the following quesitons:

- Can a computer show, on its screen, all the number from 1 till (infinity): increasing the number on screen by 1 every second?
- Can a computer send on the network line, a package that contains a number starting with 1, and increasing the number by 1 every second  (splitting large numbers into multiple packages, assuming computation is very fast, and "every second" can be "every minute", etc, as necessary)

then, the answer for the above is **YES**.

However,

- can a computer hold (in his memory/RAM/HD/whatever finite storage unit it connects to) a number, so that it starts with 1 and increase this number every x seconds?

then the answer is **NO**. At some point, the computer will be out of storage. This is because the storage is finite, and "counting to infinite" requires an infinite amount of information.

Comment: But is Infinity just endless constant generation of numbers?

Comment: that is one way to interpret infinity. What is the way you are after?  Also note that the counting can never **reach** infinity -- it can only get closer and closer and it will take it an infinite time to "complete" this task. You should look for infinity on wikipedia/google, there is tons of (very accessible) information about it. Let me know if you need pointers.